# Could not open connection: The path to the driver executable must be set

Tags: behat

I had used selenium2 ave behat but I find this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPJoO.png)

I downloaded the application geckodriver since link which exists in problem in i puts the in C:/selnium and I put this path to the  environments path but the problem remains .
version of mozilla firefox is 52.0.1 and version of geckodriver is v0.15.0

help me please and thank you

Comment: help me please ...

Comment: It looks like you should run your selenium instance with -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path to your driver" parameter

Comment: You need to include your browserDriver in selenium by using either system.setProperties or DesiredCapabilities.